# Black screen when I return to video playback activity in Android

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to play a video on the backgroud of the main activity. Right now is playing the video as I want... Buy when I press the button "Continue" to go to another Activity/View and then when I return to the main main the screen is Black... It does not start to play de video again.. If someone can help me with this I'll appreciate..Thanks guys.

This is the java code I'm using

```
  package co.siriusapps.aviation;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.VideoView;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class StarterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private VideoView videoview;
private Button mContinuar;
private String mBank;
private int mCurrentVideoPosition;
private MediaPlayer mp;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_starter);


    videoview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.mainvideo);
    videoview.setVideoURI(uri);
    videoview.start();
    videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.setLooping(true);
            if (mCurrentVideoPosition != 0) {
                mp.seekTo(mCurrentVideoPosition);
                mp.start();
            }
        }
    });




    mContinuar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mContinuar);
    mContinuar.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view){

            Spinner mBankS = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.mBank);


            switch(String.valueOf(mBankS.getSelectedItemId())){

                case "0":
                    mBank="ppa";
                    break;
                case "1":
                    mBank="pca";
                    break;
                case "2":
                    mBank="pch";
                    break;
                case "3":
                    mBank="ptl";
                    break;
                case "4":
                    mBank="asa";
                    break;
                case "5":
                    mBank="dpa";
                    break;
                case "6":
                    mBank="prepav";
                    break;
                case "7":
                    mBank="tla";
                    break;
                case "8":
                    mBank="tlh";
                    break;
                case "9":
                    mBank="teei";
                    break;


            }

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
            SharedPreferences sharedPref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(
                    getString(R.string.preferences), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            editor = sharedPref.edit();
            editor.putString("BankSelected", mBank);
            editor.commit();

            Boolean firstOpeningValue = sharedPref.getBoolean("first_opening",false);
            Boolean sessionStartedValue = sharedPref.getBoolean("session_started",false);
            Boolean premiumAccount = sharedPref.getBoolean("premium_account"+mBank,false);

            Intent intent;

            if (premiumAccount){
        intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), InitialPremiumActivity.class);
      }
      else{
          intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), InitialActivity.class);
      }

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void OnPause(){
    super.onPause();
    mCurrentVideoPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition();
    videoview.pause();
}
@Override
protected void OnResume(){
    super.onResume();
    videoview.start();
}
@Override
protected void OnDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    mp.release();
    mp = null;
}

}
```

Comment: You should make use of `onPause()` and `onResume()`. In `onPause` you should stop media player and in `onResume` you should start it again.

Comment: Yes i just added to the code but I need to put `@Override
    protected void OnResume(){
        super.onResume();
        videoview.start();
    }`   I got an error Method does not override from its superclass... I dont know what to do to get away from it @HB Do you know?

Comment: Please see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like mentioned in the comments section - You should make use of onPause() and onResume(). In onPause you should stop media player and in onResume you should start it again, as shown below:

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    if(videoview != null){
        videoview.start();
    }
}
```

You need to change this (inside `onCreate`):

```
VideoView videoview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview);
```

to this:

```
videoview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview);
```

Otherwise you will not be able to get reference to the videoview outside of `onCreate`.

---

Edit:

```
private VideoView videoview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_starter);

    videoview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoview); 

    //Your code......

}

//It should be underneath onCreate
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    if(videoview != null){
        videoview.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes i did it exactly as you're saying... But when I type `@Override` i got an error Method does not override from its superclass...  Do you know why?

Comment: `onResume` should be outside `onCreate`, place the above underneath `onCreate`.

Comment: Ok I did it and OnResume is outside of onCreate but it keeps saying Method does not override from its superclass :/ @HB

Comment: Please edit you code in your question to what you are using now

Comment: Check it out---

Comment: it should be `onResume ` and not `OnResume`, same for `onDestroy` and `onPause`

Comment: omg... Thank You Sr... I didn't notice that.  Stupid mistake...Thanks so much. I appreciate